# difference in result of two mysql queries

Tags: mysql

I am working on mysql queries which results different value.

One is like

```
select column1 from table1 where condition1
```

the other being

```
select column2 from table1 where condition2
```

both queries return a single int. I want to find difference of both of these.

Tried minus, intersect but they are saying error in mysql syntax.

Original query:

```
SELECT (SELECT MAX(date_time) maxDate FROM history WHERE ID = 2593 AND from = 1) - SELECT (SELECT MIN(date_time) minDate FROM history WHERE ID = 2593 AND to = 13)
```

Comment: Why don't you simply calculate the difference in your application code?

Comment: If both of them are fetching an int, then you can simply put a minus sign between them.

Comment: Please post the full query you have tried

Comment: You didn't think it was relevant to mention that the data type you're subtracting is a DATETIME?

Comment: @DigitalChris date_time is the column name .. column type is "int" as i just mentioned in the question. :)

Comment: Also you're using reserved words as column names; not a good practice. To get around it, surround them with backticks http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: You have an extra select after the  minus.  This is the problem

Comment: @DigitalChris that is kind of abstraction i am using before posting the query here... :) Thanks for the suggestions though

Comment: You mean you don't really have a `from` column and a `to` column? Why would you "abstract" them? Give us the real values o.O

Comment: from was 'from_status' and to was 'to_status'. It does not make any sense to downvote a question for that. 'from' and 'to' works fine in MySql DBMS tool i am using. They are not being flagged as an error there. I posted after checking there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
select (select column1 from table1 where condition1)-(select column2 from table1 where condition2)
```

Comment: thanks. but minus does not work for me. getting the error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax t

Comment: You say noz's solution didn't work for you, but your query you added to the question is not the same...

Comment: SELECT (SELECT MAX(date_time) maxDate FROM history WHERE ID = 2593 AND from = 1) - (SELECT MIN(date_time) minDate FROM history WHERE ID = 2593 AND to = 13)

Answer (score 2):

You should cast the returned value

```
((int) select column1 from table1 where condition1) - ((int) select column2 from table1 where condition2)
```

or double instead of int, depends on you